# Mesh Deform not working in render

Tags: animation, modifiers, hair

TL;DR: Mesh deform doesn't work when i render my animation, but it does in viewport (Blender 2.82)

I was looking for a quick way to animate the ponytail hair of my character and came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAOp0DpYZEk). I followed the tutorial and managed to make the low-poly-hair react to the movement of the character. The animation is not perfect, but it is close enough. Sadly, when i render the scene the ponytail doesn't move at all. The softbody-container used as a reference for the mesh deform modifier works just fine if made visible, but the hair are still stuck mid-air. I tried to move up and down the modifiers but the result is always the same. The ponytail has, in this order, Mirror, MeshDeform, Armature, Subdivision and Collision modifiers.

Thank you in advance if anyone could help me with this, cause i couldn't figure it out by myself.

[Link to download the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TkdLbcIoM2dfnq4OH9vtauq2uz_YHHaY/view?usp=sharing).

Viewport:
[image: Viewport]

Render:
[image: Render]

Comment: Did you remember to bake the simulation?

Comment: Yes, both the soft body and the dress are baked. The cloth simulation works fine but the hair don't.

Comment: Do you have a modifier with different settings for render and viewport? For example different subdivision resolution, or just something different for render.

Comment: @FFeller No, that's the first thing i checked. Both Viewport and Render subdivision are set to 2.

Comment: I added a link to download the .blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another Blender user on Reddit helped me figure this out.
To solve this i had to **apply the scale** on the soft body target for the Mesh Deform.